# Azure FunctionApp is not showing Function(fx) option

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have Created a Function APP to work on Timer Trigger Function and once after creating it, I am able to Create Functions but Function(fx) option is missing in Functions Section. Is it the new feature or Am I missing something.

Comment: what do you mean by function(fx) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it the new feature or Am I missing something.

Yes, the UI presentation of function app has been changed, if you want to create a function in function app you can create in this way:

[image]

The f(x) in Functions tab is not available now, but you can access or open the function using below way(if you created function in portal or deployed to it you can open or access in below way):

[image]

After opening it, the UI is same as before:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It clears my doubt. I have developed the TimerTrigger function and deployed the code using visual studio publish. But it is not running as per the schedule. But If I do Code+Test it is working. How to schedule the run after publishing. Do I need to create the schedule in the configuration

Comment: You don't need to create a function azure if you are creating in local and then publish, function will be created automatically after publishsing, so it will automatically run after publishing only

Comment: But, glad I could solve your problem

Comment: @RithwikBojja, I have developed the code and it is running locally
` public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)`
But When I deployed the code it is listing in Functions section in FunctionApp but it is not running for every 2 minutes

Comment: Thanks. Had no clue this change was made.

Comment: @Anil, Gald it helped you.